# How to set the IsSelected property for a treeview which contains a Textblock

Tags: wpf, treeview, textblock, selected

I created a TreeView and inside of the TreeView is a Textblock located:

```
 <TreeView x:Name="tvBelege" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MinHeight="200" MaxHeight="300" Margin="5,5,5,5" SelectedItemChanged="TvBelege_SelectedItemChanged">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="local:Beleg" ItemsSource="{Binding Projektphasen}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 </TreeView>
```

After loading the Dialog an item should be selected automatically  like this:

[image]

But there is no **property** or **function** like select or IsSelected to set. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Add an `IsSelected` property to your `Beleg` class and define an `ItemContainerStyle` that binds the `IsSelected` property of the `TreeViewItem` container to it:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvBelege" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MinHeight="200" MaxHeight="300" Margin="5,5,5,5" SelectedItemChanged="TvBelege_SelectedItemChanged">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="local:Beleg" ItemsSource="{Binding Projektphasen}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

You then set the property of the `Beleg` object to be selected in your view model.